# How to inspect elements IE settings options -Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, inspect-element

I need to launch IE browser and click on IE settings option and do some action. I launched IE browser but not able to click on Settings as inspect element is only restricted to webelements but not to IE settings tools.

Does anyone know solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Although, It is not possible to access browser setting panel. 
But We can achieve some scenario using desired capability:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities =  DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
//Examples
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);   
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
capabilities.setCapability("allow-blocked-content", true);
capabilities.setCapability("allowBlockedContent", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
capabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false); 
capabilities.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().getBrowserName());
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
//it is used to initialize the IE driver 
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

**Note: Please provide exact details what you want to achieve.**

As per your requirement >> add new entry to add site to apps option in tools

************ **Solution** ***********

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Note: Above code will do, if not please handle according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need to add new entry to add site to apps option in tools. Any idea on this

Comment: @PoornimaHegde : I have edited my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing (ALt+X) command using any Robot or Action Class once you lauch your browser. It will open setting tab.

Answer (score 0):

I try to search but did not get any way to access IE options and settings using Selenium.

If we talk from a browser side, Than browser will also not allow any automation to access settings.

Someone can miss use it and try to change browser settings without informing the user. Than it can be a security related issue.